# iOS Complex Query for ListView

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a model where:

```
Place:
title
address
category <--->> Category:
                title
```

And I want to have a table view that has the sections as the category names, but be able to search based on place titles. Now, what is the best way of obtaining a set of data for a table view that has only the categories and titles that match some specified searchText? I am currently putting the results in an NSDictionary, but it doesnt seem to be very efficient. Especially when performing delete type operations - I run into lots of problems. Currently I am doing the following, but woudl much rather directly return the FetchedResultsController.

```
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)getDictionaryResultsInContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *)context
                                         forSearchText: (NSString *)searchText {

    NSFetchRequest *req = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Place"];
    if(![searchText isEqualToString:@""] && searchText != nil){
        req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category.name CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (placeTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (details CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText, searchText, searchText];
        NSLog(@"ModelHelper.getResults: Search text given, creating predicate: %@", req.predicate);
    }
    req.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"placeTitle"
                                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:req
                                                                                managedObjectContext:context
                                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                           cacheName:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [controller performFetch:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"- Model Search ERROR: %@ (%@)", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }

    NSLog(@"- Got results: %i", [controller.fetchedObjects count]);

    NSMutableDictionary* ret = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(Place* obj in controller.fetchedObjects){
        if(obj != nil){
            NSManagedObjectID* categoryId = obj.category.objectID;
            if(categoryId != nil){
                NSMutableArray* ary = (NSMutableArray*)[ret objectForKey:categoryId];
                if(ary == NULL){
                    ary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    [ret setObject:ary forKey:categoryId];
                }
                [ary addObject:obj];
            }
            else {
                // Shouldnt happen
                NSLog(@"- Category was nil.");
            }
        }
        else {
            // Shouldnt happen
            NSLog(@"- Place was nil.");
        }
    }

    return(ret);
}
```

Comment: couldn't you just set the `sectionNameKeyPath` to `@"category.title"` (assuming the title is unique for all categories)

Comment: I will try that. I actually didnt realize that the sectionNameKeyPath was meant for this type of functionality. (reading more about that argument now)

Answer (score 0):

Your data model does not make sense. You really want a many-to-many relationship.

Categories only make sense if they can contain more than one place. So the `category->place` relationship has to be to-many. Optionally, one place can be in more than one category, so `place->category` also to-many; if not it should be a to-one relationship.

So either

```
Place <<----------> Category
```

or

```
Place <<--------->> Category
```

but not the version in your question. In your scenario, a Place that is a restaurant would get the category with title "Restaurant", and for the next place that is a restaurant you would have to create a new category with title "Restaurant". Does not make sense.

In the simple case (one-to-many), your predicate is

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"title CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR address CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTerm, searchTerm];
```

For the more complex case (many-to-many) you have the problem that a place can be listed in several sections. You thus have to fetch the categories, use the count of the categories places as the number of rows in each section, and filter with this predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
  @"ANY places.title CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR ANY places.address CONTAINS[cd] %@",
  searchTerm, searchTerm];
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the original question incorrect. It is as you first described. A category can have multiple places. With the first predicate, that will give me a list of places, correct? In a list view, how would you give the names of the categories for the list groups?

Comment: "With the first predicate, that will give me a list of places, correct?" - Correct. -- "In a list view, how would you give the names of the categories for the list groups?" - `placeObject.category.title`.

Comment: i guess my problem now becomes having a list of places where it shoudl be more of a 2 level deep array, right? otherwise i would have to iterate the list each time to find the number of categories and each title.